# Does CLLocationManager ever use cellular data?

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager, cellular-network

The location manager uses assisted GPS to detmine a user's location, using information from the wifi and cellular adapters to improve the accuracy and battery efficiency of returned locations. However, the documentation does not make it clear whether using the wifi/cell signal info for this involves any network communication which may consume the user's cellular data, or whether the information *about* these connections is sufficient. In short, will "startUpdatingLocation," or other location methods ever consume cellular data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location manager needs to consult remote server to resolve cell tower and wifi access point ids to lat/long. If wifi is not available, it has no option but to consume cellular data.

You can't force location manager to use GSM only: even if you set desiredAccuracy to 1 meter, location manager will try to deliver you the first reading as soon as possible and most likely it will be a result of wifi access point triangulation.

So the answer is yes, your app is going to use cellular data from time to time. However, keep in mind that under default settings iOS uses location services for it's own purposes - things like app suggestion, frequent locations feature etc. So it has to connect to Apple servers with or without your app running.

Furthermore, while I did not specifically test this, but I doubt that network traffic, which was created by location manager will be credited to your app under Cellular Data Usage section in Settings.

The bottom line - your app adds quite a few if any bytes towards the cellular data consumption and, most likely, even this amount will not be credited to your app.

Answer (score 0):

No, it only uses your cellular network to retrieve your location. It doesn't consume any cellular data, you can test this out yourself by turning off 'Mobile Network' in Settings.

Comment: I know it functions when cellular data is disabled, but that's not the same as assuming it won't use it if is enabled. For instance, Google's location services on Android will do a remote lookup (consuming data) to a db that maps wifi to physical location if an internet connection is available, but will fall back to GPS if there isn't one (assuming location mode is not set to "device only" which forces it to only use the GPS).